# HTTPS Flask using POST data

Tags: python, ssl, flask, https

Thanks for reading in advance.

I have a working Apache2 server which is currently successfully serving both :80 and :443.  I have a simple FLASK based site at the moment that is being served HTTPS successfully.  using Mod_wsgi and self-signed certs at the moment.

Here's where I run into trouble.   I have a login which uses POST data to send info back from a FORM in my template to my server for user authentication.   It works fine in HTTP however in HTTPS I get:

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Having googled around for a couple hours it seems like there could be some mix of context settings and or app extensions that could be used with the server SSL certs,keys to help here. But I'm a babe in the woods when it comes to SSL.  Could anyone point me to what changes I need to make to adapt to SSL handling of client/server in Flask?  I've tried SSLify (didn't work - same error)

Very Best Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

You need an SSL server in front of your Flask Application. Google how to configure `flask nging ssl` if you want `nginx` or `flask apache ssl` if you want Apache's `httpd` server.

If you really want to serve `https` content directly from your Flask Application (which I wouldn't recommend), you can [follow this blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https).

Comment: Hey so are you saying I need a server INFRONT of my apache2 SSL setup?  Right now I have apache2 serving SSL successfully.   IE Flask does serve a template over https connection (using apache2 with Mod_Wsgi).  Where things break is upon submission of a Form with POST data - I get the error message.  Again thanks for the comment